# Can not move file using file object in adobe air

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flex3, flex4.5

I have an update utility in adobe air that needs to replace an existing file in application directory. but when I try to move file in application directory it throws IOError describing that file can not be deleted.

I did the following;

```
protected function onBtnTest(event:MouseEvent):void
{    
  try
  {
    service = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath + File.separator +
      "assets" + File.separator + "oldFile.exe");        

    servic_ = new File(File.userDirectory.nativePath + File.separator + "newFile.exe");

    servic_.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, OnMoveComplete);
    servic_.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, OnIOError);


    if(service.exists)
      servic_.moveToAsync(service, true);

  }
  catch(err:Error)
  {
    trace(err.message);
  }


}

private function OnMoveComplete(event:Event):void
{
  trace("Move Complete.");      
  trace("File Deleted.");
}

private function OnIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
  trace("OnIOError.");     
}
```

it always execute OnIOError function. but when I try to move same file to some other directory it works fine. How can I do this. Thanks

Comment: Why can't the file be deleted?  Are there any other details?  Is it a permission issue on the directory?  If the file locked by some other open process?  What operating system are you running the app on?

Comment: I think it is a permission issue. It is not locked by any other process. I am using window 7. when I run my application as administrator by right clicking on it and choosing run as administrator. it works fine. can we make our installed application that always run in administrator mode? Thanks

Comment: There is nothing you can do in code to make sure that the app is run in administrator mode; that will have to be done by the user in the operating system level.  You can't usually assume that the user has access to run things as administrator.  It is best to use the directories that the user should have access to, such as the applicationStorageDirectory or userDirectory.  The full list is documented here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one thing: You CAN'T write into the application directory, it's a flex security.

There is nothing you can do, sorry. Think about using another directory. Personally, I use the application storage directory instead.

Comment: If I want to replace a file that is in application directory. there is no way I can do this in code?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This in not possible in pure Flex. It's a security leak. I recommend you to use another directory (user directory, application directory, etc...). But, if you want **REALLY** want to modify the application directory, maybe you can try using an external worker (command line, executable, etc...) which will do the work for you. But I don't recommend you to do it (By the way, I have never tried it)

Comment: Edit: Missing a word and everything change. At the second line, in the parentheses, it's not `application directory` but `application storage directory`. My bad, sorry.